# Как передать массив с js на php с помощью ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ребят, скажу сразу, сам не представляю как правильно сформулировать данный вопрос.
Потому все по полкам:
Есть кнопка `id="ban_autor"` по нажатию на которую показывается div `id="form_ban_autor"`
В div'е со всех полей (на скрытые поля не обращайте внимания - их вижу только я) по их id нужно получить их значения (value) и записать в массив в виде `key - value`
Так получаю значения полей -

```
$('#reason_ban_autor').val()  
$('#id_ban_autor').val()  
$('#message_ban_autor').val()  
$('#time_ban_autor').val()
```

В итоге написал код на jquery, но

```php
$array_ban_autor = $_POST['result'];  
if (isset($array_ban_autor)) {  
    print_r($array_ban_autor);  
}
```

молчит как партизан. т.е. данные не приходят.
Я 100% делаю что то не так. Но что именно и в каком месте - не знаю. И прошу вас ткнуть меня носом где ошибки и подскажите, пожалуйста, как их исправить.

UPD: добавил обновленный код js, код php и скрин ответа `alert(response);`

```js
<?php 
        $array_ban_autor = $_POST;
        if (isset($array_ban_autor)) {
            var_dump($array_ban_autor);
        }
    ?>
    // результат array(0) { }


$(document).ready(function() {


  $('#form_ban_autor #set_ban').bind('click', function() {
    var array_ban_autor = {
      reason: $('#reason_ban_autor').val(),
      id: $('#id_ban_autor').val(),
      message: $('#message_ban_autor').val(),
      time: $('#time_ban_autor').val()
    };
    console.log(array_ban_autor);
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/footer',
      data: array_ban_autor,
      success: function(response) {
        /* код обработчика успешного ответа. */
        alert(response);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<button id="ban_autor" class="btn">бан</button>
<div id="form_ban_autor" style="display: none;">
  <label>Причина бана</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="reason_ban_autor"><br>
  <input id="id_ban_autor" type="hidden" value="<?= $id; ?>">
  <input id="message_ban_autor" type="hidden" value="<?= $message; ?>">
  <label>Время бана</label><br>
  <select id="time_ban_autor">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Выбери время</option>
    <option value="1">1 час</option>
    <option value="12">12 часов</option>
    <option value="24">24 часа</option>
  </select><br><br>
  <button id="set_ban">Выдать бан <img src="images/krutoi.png"></button>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения])

```
  ];
```

Comment: Вот теперь всё работает. 

В JS формируется массив, передается и обрабатывается сервером. Всё хорошо. 

в $_POST лежат нужные вам переменные. 

$_POST["reason"] = "проверка JS";
$_POST["id"] = "4";

Дальше работайте как вам нужно с php, а на success в AJAX можете поставить просто alert("Бан успешно выдан"); - это сообщение будет показываться при выполнении php без ошибок.

Comment: Да, ещё у вас url - /footer, как по мне - лучше сделать отдельный обработчик, чтобы у вас не пересекались различные POST переменные от других форм.

Если же разделения не планируется - добавьте ещё одну переменную в массив, например `type: ban`, а на сервере php код процесса бана кладите в `if($_POST["type"] == "ban"){  /* здесь код бана используя $_POST['reason'] и прочие переменные из массива */ }`

Comment: url: '/footer' - это объясните

Comment: @Kirill здесь все просто) в файле ```.htaccess``` прописано правило которое обрезает расширение ```.php``` в адресной строке и все ссылки, перенаправления и т.д. без проблем работают в таком виде

Comment: @adudnik.ru обработчик сделал в другом файле но все равно получаю пустой массив. ну как так, не понимаю :( как мне получить и вывести на экран(увидеть) содержание этого массива?

Comment: Так, кажется я понял. Если ты пытаешься открыть в браузере /footer и увидеть там массив - то ничего не увидишь. Данные в POST передаются во время работы скрипта и только тогда существуют (пока скрипт выполняется). "Видишь" ты массив в alert(response), вот response - это то, что показывает footer.php в момент обращения скрипта. 

Если тебе нужны данные для отладки - просто задай переменные, например так $reason = "причина" и пиши свой код по ним.
Потом когда всё будет написано просто замени переменные на $reason = $_POST["reason"] и скрипт будет работать по обращению из AJAX.

Comment: в передаче данных посредством отправки через ajax уже знаком, но никогда не передавал целый массив и вот такая ` data: array_ban_autor, ` запись меня запутала. `data: { result : array_ban_autor }` вот так понятно с чем имею дело и как с этой петрушкой работать дальше

Comment: Искренне благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не правильно формируете data массив (делаете это по тип php через `=>`, а нужно через `:` ).

Вот так правильно:

```
var array_ban_autor = {
    reason : $('#reason_ban_autor').val(),
    id : $('#id_ban_autor').val(),
    message : $('#message_ban_autor').val(),
    time : $('#time_ban_autor').val()
};
```

И в запрос их передавайте вот так:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/footer',
    data: array_ban_autor,
    success: function(response){
    /* код обработчика успешного ответа. */
    alert(response);
    } 
});
```

А на сервере получайте так:

```
<?php
$array_ban_autor = $_POST;
if (isset($array_ban_autor)) {
    print_r($array_ban_autor);
}
```

### Пример формирования data и передачи на мой сервер запроса

Нажмите "выполнить код", затем на кнопку "выдать бан"

```js
// jquery 3.4.1
$(document).ready(function() {
  var array_ban_autor = {
    reason: $('#reason_ban_autor').val(),
    id: $('#id_ban_autor').val(),
    message: $('#message_ban_autor').val(),
    time: $('#time_ban_autor').val()
  };
  console.log(array_ban_autor);
 
  $('#form_ban_autor #set_ban').on('click', function() {
  console.log("отправляем запрос");
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'https://adudnik.ru/POST_test.php',
      data: array_ban_autor,
      success: function(response) {
      console.log("получен ответ");
        /* код обработчика успешного ответа. */
        alert(response);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<div id="form_ban_autor">
  <button id="set_ban">Выдать бан <img src="images/krutoi.png"></button>
  <label>Причина бана</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="reason_ban_autor" value="причина" /><br>
  <input id="id_ban_autor" type="hidden" value="1">
  <input id="message_ban_autor" type="hidden" value="сообщение">
  <label>Время бана</label><br>
  <select id="time_ban_autor">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">Выбери время</option>
    <option value="1">1 час</option>
    <option value="12">12 часов</option>
    <option value="24">24 часа</option>
  </select><br><br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: на ```:``` консоль ругает Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'

Comment: Сейчас поправлю ответ

Comment: Прошу прощение, не исправил на Ваш пример массив. но данные в php все равно не приходят. и значение инпутов я получаю именно с php и они там есть

Comment: Написал вам подробную реализацию с примером запроса к моему ресурсу и выводом ответа через JS.

Comment: поправил немного код и в консоль: {reason: "проверка js", id: "4", message: "проверка работы системы банов", time: "24"}
reason: "проверка js"
id: "4"
message: "проверка работы системы банов"
time: "24" получил все необходимые данные. но в php почему то глухо

Comment: $array_ban_autor = $_POST;
    if (isset($array_ban_autor)) {
        var_dump($array_ban_autor);
    }  получаю  array(0) { } не понимаю почему массив пустой

Comment: Я вам написал полный код, да еще и пример на своем сервере обработчика положил. Запустите код из ответа, нажмите "выдать бан", убедитесь что все работает. Скопируйте код к себе и поменяйте значения на нужные вам.

Comment: в том то и беда. как мне обработать данные на серваке если я получаю пустой массив array(0) { } данные с этого миссива мне нужно в бд записать, а записывать то нечего)

Comment: Обновите в вопросе код на тот, который используете после моего ответа. Просто скопируйте и вставьте html, js, и php новые.